# Creating a sequence in spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot specifically spring data jpa for working with the database and the database manager is postgres. I need to create a sequence that will be used in the conformation of an attribute.
Specifically my attribute is called classifier (this attribute is not the primary key) and it is formed with a given string and a consecutive number (which would be the value given by the sequence) example FMFC-COMP-1234

currently I create the sequence with postgres using

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_name START WITH 1;
```

but I wish I could create it from spring boot. Any help will be welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be clear you want spring boot to generate your field content with the given string concatenated with the sequence value? It that is the case I don't think there is a out of the box way, a few options from top of my head: 1- Use a trigger in the database; 2- use entity LifeCycle (not sure if possible); 3 - use an [IdentityGenerator](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-combine-the-hibernate-assigned-generator-with-a-sequence-or-an-identity-column/). There other options as well, though I would start with option 3 above, seems the easiest and closest for what you need

Comment: I am now using the @PrePersist annotation for the formation of the field, which allows me to form the attribute just before persisting the entity, at that moment I make a query in which I obtain the next value of the sequence and concatenate with the given string

Comment: Sounds good. You can also add an answer of your own. If no one else gives you a better option you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used the following tags in your Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "schools")
class School {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "school_id_seq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "school_id_seq", sequenceName = "school_id_seq",  allocationSize=1)
  @Column(name = "id")
  Integer id;
  String name;
  String postcode;
}
```

Application.properties (policy can be changed)

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto : update
```

This generates the following DDL on app startup:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS school_id_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE schools
(
    id       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name     VARCHAR(255),
    postcode VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_schools PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```